# Implementing a Flutter Future on Button Press

Tags: flutter

Im currently still a beginner trying to figure out how to run a future/futurebuilder on button press.

I already checked out some of the answers here but it only hide/display the widget I want to show while running the function for futurebuilder as the app starts.

I want the function to complete first, then display either the state of Not Loading, Loading, Complete/Error

An excerpt of my code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var myData;

  Future<Null> getData() async {
    Future<String> _calculation() async => Future<String>.delayed(
          const Duration(seconds: 15),
          () => 'Loaded',
        );

    setState(() {
      myData = _calculation().timeout(
        const Duration(seconds: 5),
        onTimeout: () => 'Error',
      ) as String;
    });
  }

  Widget buildThis() {
    return FutureBuilder(
        // future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (myData == 'Loaded') {
        return Text(myData);
      } else if (myData == 'Error') {
        return Text(myData);
      }
      return Text('Loading');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              MaterialButton(
                shape: const CircleBorder(),
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.refresh,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: getData(),
              ),
              buildThis(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This was based on a tutorial I found but it had some issues with null safety :(

Comment: `I want to complete first and then show the loading, completion etc` How is this possible?

Comment: I think you're being confused with the features of FutureBuilder. You can actually check the status of the data by: `snapshot.hasData`

Comment: `FutureBuilder` has its own property to check state. Like `snapshot.state==ConnectionState.loading` +error,done. etc.

Comment: i see. i didnt know snapshot has its own states. is there anywhere you can point to the connection state? some samples or guide on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and did what i wanted based on one of the answer (@is-a).
I would like to know your thoughts on this kind of coding.
I will also explore more on connectionStates as per comment (@Yeasin Sheikh) and update this answer after my finding.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? myData;
  Widget? loading;

  Future<String> _calculation() async => Future<String>.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 10),
        () => 'Loaded',
      );

  Future<void> getData() async {
    var a = 'Loading';

    setState(() {
      loading = buildThis();
      myData = a;
    });

    a = await _calculation();

    setState(() {
      myData = a;
    });

    a = await _calculation().timeout(
      const Duration(seconds: 5),
      onTimeout: () => 'Error',
    );

    setState(() {
      myData = a;
    });
  }

  Widget buildThis() {
    return FutureBuilder(builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (myData == 'Loaded') {
        return Text(myData!);
      }
      if (myData == 'Error') {
        return Text(myData!);
      }
      if (myData == 'Loading') {
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      // first/primary widget
      return MaterialButton(
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        shape: const CircleBorder(),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.refresh,
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        ),
        onPressed: getData,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              buildThis(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code to to implement it:

```html
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? myData;

  Future<String> _calculation() async => Future<String>.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 3),
        () => 'Loaded',
      );

  Future<void> getData() async {
    var a = await _calculation().timeout(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      onTimeout: () => 'Error',
    );

    setState(() {
      myData = a;
    });
  }

  Widget buildThis() {
    return FutureBuilder(
        // future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (myData == 'Loaded') {
        return Text(myData!);
      } else if (myData == 'Error') {
        return Text(myData!);
      }
      return Text('Loading');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              buildThis(),
              MaterialButton(
                shape: const CircleBorder(),
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.refresh,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: getData,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```